# How to get values out of a Background Worker's event args?

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

In a method, I populate a list of IDs and pass them to my Background Worker. When I try to access this object, I'm getting a null value and I don't really know why.

```
    public void Submit()
    {
        if (DataModels.Count == 0)
            return;

        List<long> docRefIds = new List<long>();

        foreach (var row in DataModels)
        {
            if (row.PrintAck == true)
                docRefIds.Add(Convert.ToInt32(row.DOCUMENT_REF_ID));
        }

        BackgroundWorker worker_Acknowledge = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker_Acknowledge.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_Acknowledge_DoWork);
        worker_Acknowledge.RunWorkerCompleted +=new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(worker_Acknowledge_RunWorkerCompleted);
        worker_Acknowledge.RunWorkerAsync(docRefIds.ToArray());
    }
```

Then in the DoWork event...

```
    private void worker_Acknowledge_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var wkService = WorkItem.Services.Get<MyService>();

        if (wkService == null)
            return;

        long?[] ids = e.Argument as long?[];
        string errorMessage;
        e.Result = wkService.SaveDetails(ids, out errorMessage);
    }
```

I've set a breakpoint on the last line of my `Submit` method, and docRefIds has the valid data I'd expect. In fact, `e.Argument` has the 4 values but then `ids` is null after that line executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course after exhausting my resources and finally posting here, I realize my mistake.

My *list* wasn't nullable, so the cast in the DoWork event wasn't working. In my Submit method, the list should be declared as such:

```
    List<long?> docRefIds = new List<long?>();
```

Comment: This is why you should use casts and not the `as` operator in cases where the given value *must* be of the given type.  You should only use `as` when it's entirely valid for the given object to not be of the type you are planning to treat it as.  If you were casting it here you'd see an exception that would tell you exactly what you were doing wrong, rather than getting a null reference exception that gives the false impression that something entirely different is going on.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, I'll keep that in mind. Kind of just copying how similar things were done on another control where they used `as`